# Are portable solar panels useful on pack trips?

Tags: gear, hiking, backpacking

Have you used portable folding solar panels (5-20W) like Anker or GoalZero with much success?  It seems like they would really only work well on a pack trip if you have a day off periodically to recharge equipment, otherwise I would think there's just not enough time to charge up your gear.